# Is there another way of running your created UI using GUI Builder in eclipse(Codenameone) beside this line of code: "new MyGuiBuilderForm().show()"?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, codenameone

Is there another way of running your created UI using GUI Builder in eclipse(Codenameone) beside this line of code: `new MyGuiBuilderForm().show()`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What kind of alternative are you looking for?  CN1 offers a few different ways to build UIs such as hand-coding, using the GUI builder, using the CN1ML plugin (basically writing the UI in html), and I'm sure there are other approaches also.

Answer (score 1):

Beside using theme , you can create form  by coding as shown below

```
Form form = new Form("Hello");
form.add(new Button("Test"));
form.show();
```